# Best practice for modeling tables of monthly data

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

If I have a flat csv file with columns of data corresponding to days of a month, what is the best practice for mapping this data to @Entity classes in Java EE. The example is for the JHU Covid 19 data. They update a csv file for confirmed cases and deaths (US and Global) by adding new data every day so the file grows by one column per day. [Sample file](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv) 
I've built this application [www.coronaviruscharts.net](http://coronaviruscharts.net) but I'm not sure my approach was the correct one. I parse  the csv file and create individual files for each month, then load those files to a MySql database. My entity classes map to the individual month tables. I have a DAO for each month, and services to get data for each month. This means I have to create new entities and services for every month but the code is identical except for the entity I reference. For example, I have a JanuaryService, FebruaryService etc. The alternative seemed to be to avoid parsing the original file into individual months and loading the data to one table, but then I thought I would have to rebuild the application every day to add a new filed to account for the new day's data.

Comment: That's terrible database design. The schema doesn't change just because the month changes, so there's no need to have different database tables for it. As if that weren't bad enough, there certainly is no need to have different entities, daos or services for each month. I would even question whether that kind of data warrants entities at all, as it's the data is clearly relational and is a lot easier and faster to handle with straight SQL than when converted to entities.

Comment: If you think you need to rebuild the app every day, then you have an additional design flaw. There's no reason why you couldn't design the database and the application to handle data from multiple days, months and years. A rebuild would be needed only for a significant change in the schema or behaviour, not the changing of a month. Ah, I see you're adding a new column every day. There's your design flaw. You're directly translating the sample file to a database table, that's wrong. You'll need to read up on some database basics first.

Comment: I'm not adding a new column every day, John Hopkins University are adding a new column every day. This is data related to Covid 19 and they add data as it emerges.
Is the answer then to have all the data in one table and use SQL queries to get the data I want rather than mapping the data to entity classes? What is best practice?

Comment: They're adding a new column to human readable CSV every day. You're thinking of adding a new column to a database table every day. The first one is acceptable, but the second one isn't. You'll need a different database design, and conversion so a new **column** in the CSV results in new **rows** in the database. One table won't be enough.

Comment: This answers some of the question, but the other problem then is that there can be both new rows and new columns on a given day. The rows are locations, columns are, for example number of cases on a particular day. If up to today's date location A doesn't have any cases of covid 19 it is not included in the file. If they report their first case tomorrow, location A is added as a new row tomorrow, along with the new column for the number of cases.

Comment: Your database design needs to reflect that. The locations need to be in their own table to allow new locations being added, the case data needs to be in its own table since there's new data every day. [Third normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) is what you should be aiming at. Since there's so little data you could use entities too (speedwise), but from a design point of view it's sort of odd since the entity would represent a single day's cases in a specific location, and is that really a unit your program works with? A single day?

Comment: Sweet, dividing the locations and data into two tables is the piece that I wasn't aware of. The entity should represent all the data for a specific location, from the date of the first reported case until today. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: The entity shouldn't represent all the data, otherwise that would mean a completely different database schema. Your service might aggregate the data, but an entity would still represent a single day. But since your service aggregates the data, the entity is pretty useless and you could just use native SQL. At least that would be the proper design, but you'd have to go through quite a lot of relational theory, so...well, let's hope you'll get started with this at least.